# Eclipse: Change the block comment style of ctrl+shift+/

Tags: java, eclipse

The keyboard shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> produces comments in the format of:

```
/*comment*/
```

How can I change the shortcut so that it adds a space before and after the asterisk?

```
/* comment */
```

Many thanks!

Comment: i dont find any point in doing that... why you wanna do it.

Comment: It's for improve readability and code style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For formatting the values you should try following thing.

<kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Hope this will help you.

Comment: this shortcut doesn't do anything in my eclipse

Comment: Go to Window > Preferences > General > Keys and check there.

Comment: oh my bad. I didn't realised you mean apply Ctr+Shift+F to the whole "/*comment*/"
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that you can't neverhteless you can reapply code formatting (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>) and it will reformat with space.