# Is it possible to modify Eclipse's comment behavior to add the slashes at the current level of indentation, rather than at the beginning of the row?

Tags: java, eclipse, comments

By default, pressing the Comment out shortcut keys `Ctrl` + `/`, has behavior like this:

[image]

Notice that the `//` get added at the left-most position of the row.

Is there a way to set it so that the `//` appear at the same level of indention as the code that is being commented out?

e.g.
[image]

Perhaps a Python habit, but I find it much easier to parse when everything is at the same indention level.

Is there a way to change where the slashes show up?

Comment: +1: A picture is worth a thousand words, but a video is worth a thousand pictures. Well, in this case, is an animation.

Comment: Wow moving-stuff . Very nice ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.
[go to this link for detailed info](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Default-Format-Settings-in-Eclipse)

First go to Preferences, then

> On the left side of the box, expand the Java option, then expand Code
>   Style and finally click Formatter

You'll land on the Java-Profile page:
[image]

The other, temporary way is  via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> shortcut ( [Eclipse: Change the block comment style of ctrl+shift+/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534730/eclipse-change-the-block-comment-style-of-ctrlshift) ) . So you'd highlight those comments, and  press the combo.

I would then also use a shortcut for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> , like <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> (press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> , 'keys' to get the preferences page.

Comment: @PaulBellora - Yeeeeeeeaah i know ;-)

Comment: Can someone expand on this? Ctrl-/ still exhibits the undesirable behaviour - having to run format each time defeats the purpose of having a comment shortcut.

Comment: @Coffee What do I do after opening the Formatter profile editor? You showed a screenshot, but didn't mention what to change there. Also how does this help the asker achieve what he is asking for? He doesn't want to auto-format the code. Ctrl-Shift-F also not comment out the non-comment code - it merely formats the code.

Comment: @faintsignal I used to use Column Selection Mode to quickly insert comments in multiple lines at the correct indentation level. Sure, it's not as quick as Ctrl-/ but it's still much better than messing with the code formatting. (Enter column selection, click and drag vertically where you want to insert the two //, then type in the two // - they magically appear on every line in your column selection. Exit column selection mode when done. To speed up the process, I added a handy button on the toolbar to enter/exit column selection.)